# RODBC Error Code 202 When Trying to Connect to DB

Tags: r, rodbc

I'm getting errors like the following when I try to connect to a database using RODBC:

ch <- odbcConnect("getdata",uid='uid',pwd='pwd')
    [RODBC] ERROR: state , code 202, message ��������������������

What is code 202? And what is that unreadable message supposed to be? I'm running R 3.0.2 on OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of this error message by recompiling the psqlodbc driver without unicode support.

I still can't connect using RODBC though.